# Recommended papers on Deep Ordinal Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, ranking

Can people please recommend papers on Deep Ordinal Regression?

I'm looking for both the basic papers and the current important state-of-the-art ones - basically, everything that one "must" know in this field.

Thanks :)